# Where in the bible is Jesus referred to as Jesus bin Miriam?

Tags: life-of-jesus, virgin-mary, verse-identification

I've heard that there is a reference to Jesus as 'Jesus bin Miriam' (may have misspelled Miriam), however I can't find the reference.  It may only be in some versions.

Any suggestions?

Citation:  [The Jesus of History versus the Christ of Faith](https://youtu.be/7VOMFjQfJ8w?t=38m7s) 38:07

Comment: Welcome!  Could you tell us where you've heard this?  If you haven't done so already, I hope you'll take the [tour].  Thanks!

Comment: It was mentioned in a talk by Reza Aslan, I'll get a better citation when I get home.

Comment: @Nathaniel added the citation, if I can find the time then I'll post that too.

Comment: @Nathaniel Just added the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Mark 6:1-6)

1 He went away from there and came to his hometown, and his disciples followed him. 2 And on the Sabbath he began to teach in the synagogue, and many who heard him were astonished, saying, “Where did this man get these things? What is the wisdom given to him? How are such mighty works done by his hands? 3 Is not this the carpenter, the **son of Mary** and brother of James and Joses and Judas and Simon? And are not his sisters here with us?” And they took offense at him. 4 And Jesus said to them, “A prophet is not without honor, except in his hometown and among his relatives and in his own household.” 5 And he could do no mighty work there, except that he laid his hands on a few sick people and healed them. 6 And he marveled because of their unbelief. And he went about among the villages teaching.

Edit: The phrase could be just spoken in Hebrew translation in the video; we shouldn't expect that the speaker believed that Mark was written in Aramaic or Hebrew. Some commentaries does mention that it is indeed pejorative to call someone like that. I don't know about any such aramaic original MSS discovered of Mark. You should search on http://www.csntm.org/ for such MSS evidence. Orthodox Jewish Bible which is a weird translation that adds so much Jewish and yiddish terms making it half english translation mentions that phrase; it is an unpopular bible version  --

> [Mark 6:3](https://www.bible.com/bible/130/mark.6.3.ojb) Is not this one the Naggar (Carpenter), Ben Miryam? The
>   brother of Yaakov*, Yosef, Yehuda and Shimon? And, are not his achayot
>   here with us? And they were taking offense at Rebbe, Melech
>   HaMoshiach.

Comment: Was Mark written in a Semitic language (Aramaic or Hebrew) or in Koine Greek?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast There's some debate that Mark might have actually been written in Latin originally, but it's generally agreed the entire New Testament was originally written in Greek.

Comment: @Geremia You got me curious. Do you know who has suggested that Mark was written in Latin? There is one ancient source, Papias of Hierapolis, who says that Matthew originally wrote his Gospel “in the Hebrew language” (probably what we would call Aramaic). But I have never heard of a Latin Mark.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex [Baronius et al. claim St. Mark's gospel was originally in Latin.](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/scripture/newtestament/intromark.htm) There's even a theory of [Marcan priority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcan_priority).  Also, I've heard that about St. Matthew's gospel, too. St. Jerome thought so: "I am speaking of the New Testament, which, without doubt, was written in Greek, with the exception of the Apostle Matthew, who first in Judæa published the Gospel of Christ in Hebrew." ([source](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/scripture/newtestament/intromark.htm)).

Comment: @Geremia I am aware three gospels being originally written in the Koine Greek, one in a Semitic language. I challenged Michael16 to back up / support Mark as using *Jesus bin Miriam?* (not a Greek term) rather than Jesus son of Mary(presumably in Greek).  There is reference in the Gospels of Jesus saying something not in Greek, which is translated in the text: (*My God, my God, why have you abandoned me* being one example).  Based on which source is being cited or what scholars have uncovered, my hope was that there was a scroll / fragment that had such a citation or dual entry.

Comment: @Geremia I had not heard that a gospel was originally found in Latin, thanks for that link/tidbit.  Marcan priority is a consistent theme in biblical scholarship that I am familiar with.

Comment: Thanks @Michael16, Reza specifically uses the term "bin Miriam".  Do you know if that exists in any English translations or is it only in Hebrew\Aramaic?

Comment: It wasn't clear that the question specifically asks about the language as exactly miriyam in Heb. So am I supposed to delete the answer?

Comment: @Michael16, no, I think it's a good answer (I marked it as such).  Just elaborating.

Comment: @Michael16 I'd leave the answer up.  Part of my concern is that the speaker in the video uses Bin Miriam; scripture does not, per se, as Marc was not written in Aramaic AFAIK.  The point in the video is that passage in Mark being unique: it's the only place where that form is used. He suggests that the term is pejorative.  I had hoped that you knew of versions of Mark's gospel that were preserved or found in Aramaic or Hebrew; "bin Mariam" is an inference ... how the speaker arrives at that form is rational: they spoke Aramaic in Nazareth, Jesus' home town, where that passage takes place.